# Getting the business hours from the foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to get a venue's business hours via the foursquare API. Can't seem to find it in the docs.

Is there a way to do it? The official app has access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [venues/VENUE_ID](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) endpoint for a venue with hours and then look for an "hours" stanza in the response. It'll look like this:

```
hours: {
  status: "Open today until 1:00 AM",
  isOpen: true,
  timeframes: [
    {
      days: "Mon,Tue,Wed,Sun",
      open: [
        {
          renderedTime: "11:00 AM–Midnight"
        }
      ],
      segments: [ ]
    },
    {
      days: "Thu–Sat",
      includesToday: true,
      open: [
        {
          renderedTime: "11:00 AM–1:00 AM"
        }
      ],
      segments: [ ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: hmm, so it's not listed in here? https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue

Also, I can't seem to find a VENUE_ID that has the "hours" stanza. Are they very rare or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We're rehauling all the website documentation post #allnew4sq, so many parts of it are no longer accurate/up-to-date. Hours information is not uniform, but any venue that shows hours on the web, should return hours via the API